# How can I achieve this image effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/chalong_wp/?gallery=this-is-gallery-build-from-custom-post-type-with-image-uploader-backend

I want to do this effect for my images with jQuery move them up and down on hover, I found a plugin that do this effect with mootools but the problem is it doesn't work well with my code.

I wonder if there is a  simple way to give this effect? Because I don't need the light box just the image effect on hover!

Comment: If you don't want the lightbox, than what do you want?

Comment: i want the up and down effect on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how exactly the site [does it](http://www.gallyapp.com/tf_themes/chalong_wp/wp-content/themes/Chalong/js/custom.js?ver=1.1)

```
$j('.home_portfolio img.frame').each(function() {
    $j(this).hover(function() { 
        $j(this).animate({top: '-10px'}, 300);
    },
    function() {    
        $j(this).animate({top: 0}, 300);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). You just need to animate the position and use some easing for a more pleasing transition effect.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tgh8m/56/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this

```
$('.hoverImg').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('padding-top','0px');
    },
    function(){
    $(this).css('padding-top','20px');
    }                 
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/SHrBQ/

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyXTB/3/)

```
$('img.frame').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top': '0px'
    }, 400);
},
function(){ 
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top': '10px'
    }, 400);
});
```